# configure: error: can not find cURL or libcurl... go to http://curl.haxx.se/ to download and then install it first

Tags: linux, curl, tcl, centos, libcurl

```
configure: error: can not find cURL or libcurl... go to http://curl.haxx.se/ to download and then install it first
```

Is the error I am getting when trying to run ./configure for TclCurl (which is what I really need), but I have curl installed on CentOS through yum, but it still gives this error.  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Install `curl-devel` or `libcurl-devel`.